# Conditional Rolling Sum using filter on groupby group rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I've been trying without success to find a way to create an "average_gain_up" in python and have gotten a bit stuck. Being new to groupby there is something of how it is treating functions that i've not managed to grasp so any intuition behind how to think through these types of problems would be helpful.

Problem: 
Create a rolling 14 day sum, only summing if the value is >0 .

```
new=pd.DataFrame([[1,-2,3,-2,4,5],['a','a','a','b','b','b']])
new= new.T #transposing into a friendly groupby format

#Group by a or b, filter to only have positive values and then sum rolling, we 
keep NAs to ensure the sum is ran over 14 values. 
groupby=new.groupby(1)[0].filter(lambda x: x>0,dropna=False).rolling(14).sum()
```

[image: frame]

Intended Sum Frame:

[image]

x.all()/len(x) result:

[image]

this throws a type error   "the filter must return a boolean result" .
from reading other answers, I understand as i'm asking if a series/frame is superior to 0 . 
The above code works with len(x), again makes sense in that context.

i tried with all() as well but it doesn't behave as intended. the .all() functions returns a single boolean per group and the sum is then just a simple rolling sum.

i've tried creating a list of booleans to say which values are positive and which are not but that also yields an error, this time i'm not sure why.

```
groupby1=new.groupby(1)[0]
groupby2=[y>0 for x in groupby1 for y in x[1] ]
groupby_try=new.groupby(1)[0].filter(lambda x:groupby2,dropna=False).rolling(2).sum()
```

1) how do i make the above code work and what is wrong in how i am thinking about it ?

2) is this the "best Practice" way to do these types of operations ?

any help appreciated, let me know if i've missed anything or any further clarification is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the doc on [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) after a `groupby`, it is not supposed to `filter` values within a group but groups as a whole if they don't meet some criteria, such as if the `sum` of all the elements of the group is above 2 then the group is kept in the first example given

One way could be to replace all the negative values by 0 in `new[0]` first, using [`np.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) for example, and then `groupby`, `rolling` and `sum` such as

```
print (np.clip(new[0],0,np.inf).groupby(new[1]).rolling(2).sum())
1   
a  0    NaN
   1    1.0
   2    3.0
b  3    NaN
   4    4.0
   5    9.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

This way prevents from modifying the data in `new`, if you don't mind you can  change the column 0 with `new[0] = np.clip(new[0],0,np.inf)` and then do `new.groupby(1)[0].rolling(2).sum()` which give the same result.

Comment: thanks a lot ! i'd read the documentation but not really understood that it could not be turned into a group row level function. is your suggested answer best practice then i assume in data science ?

Comment: @clockworkss for what concerns doing a rolling sum of 14 element per group, then using the functions `groupby`, `rolling` and `sum` are sure a good way to achieve this goal. For what concerns the not summing if the value is negative but still counting as one of the 14 element of the rolling window, then setting this value to 0 seems the easiest thing to do, `np.clip` may not be the fastest, but I think it is easy to understand wat is does.

Comment: @clockworkss in the question you talk about 14 days, does it means that the index of your data are Datetime? if yes, when you perform the rolling, do you want to see a result even for the days when the value is negative?

Comment: thanks so much for the continued help.  the index is not, i've got a separate column for date ( was trying to follow tidy data principles) and for the second question yes. I'm trying to recreate the RSI [link](http://cns.bu.edu/~gsc/CN710/fincast/Technical%20_indicators/Relative%20Strength%20Index%20(RSI).htm) so was thinking of doing a multi step process where i compute each part separately. to that end, on any given day i'll be doing the sum of neg and pos (manipulated as per the function in the link)

Comment: @clockworkss you are welcome and then I guess my answer is a good practice then :) In the case of the RSI then go have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51356176/need-to-apply-different-formulas-based-on-the-row-number-in-the-dataframe/51383089#51383089), it should give you more insight about it, and especially for the Smoothed RS, the solution can use [ewm](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html)

Comment: thanks, EWM sounds like the right fit for my next step!